# Find the range of a set of numbers

Tags: java, arraylist

hi all, just learning java,trying to figure out to find the range of a set of numbers entered thru the keyboard. Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FindRange {

    public static void main (final String args []){

        Scanner num= new Scanner( System.in);

        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println ( " Enter the first number : ");
        add.num(nextInt());
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do here?? Your code is incomplete. Variables "add" and "num" are not defined.

Comment: Not sure there is a question here. What is `add`?

Comment: Fix the compiler errors, by checking your IDE's messages and post your code again, possibly with more details on what your code does, or what you want it to do.

Comment: probably he means finding min and max of all entered numbers

Comment: I think several things are wrong since I am completely new. However, I want to prompt a user to enter a set of 10 numbers, store these numbers and thereafter find their range. Thanks !!

Comment: It looks like you don't use an IDE at all, you would see the errors.

Comment: @user3123545 ...using Eclipse for this, maybe I need to understand these errors and learn how to resolve them. Can i also post the errors from the IDE here ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to find the range inside an array & then print or use it.

You can do this like it, I am sure there is a better way of doing it, but that's what I thought of

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        ints.add(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter the first range number");
    int first = console.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the last range number");
    int last = console.nextInt();   


    ArrayList<Integer> rangedInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int min = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ints.size(); i++) {
        for (int num : ints) {          
            if (num >= first && num <= last && num > min && !rangedInts.contains(num)) {
                min = num;
                rangedInts.add(num);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int integer : rangedInts) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
}
```

Comment: However it is not proper, cause it won't work if the numbers are the same. Ill get it for you when I get back. however this line causes it && !rangedInts.contains(num)

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, however I can notice several issues in your code.
First of all, ArrayList is a generic class.
This means you can use ArrayList with the type you wish (Object type, not raw type actually).
Hence, you should write:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Funrthermore, you used Scanner class incorrectly.
In order to obtain an integer entered through the keyboard, you have to write:

```
int n = num.nextInt();
```

and write it into a loop in order to get more than one element.

Finally you can insert your number into the ArrayList.

```
a.add(n);
```

Now you should be able to write your program.

Edit:
For example an implementation could be:

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FindRange {

```
public static void main (String args []){

    Scanner num= new Scanner( System.in);
    int n = 0, min = 0, max = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i < 10 ; i++){
        System.out.println ( " Enter the number" + (i+1) + " : ");
        n = num.nextInt();
        if(i==0) //first number
            min = max = n;
        else{
            if(n < min)
                min = n;
            else if(n > max)
                max = n;
        }
        a.add(n);
     }
     System.out.println("The range is " + (max-min));
}
```

}

Comment: ....i have added the loop(for) and used a.add(n). i have an error " the method add(int) is undefined for the  type scanner".

Comment: in my code a is an ArrayList, not a Scanner. Scanner is called num. Did you paste my code? Scanner's method is nextInt()